# Is "I should behave morally" a moral statement?

Tags: ethics

I am a new hand in learning English. And I feel confused when I am trying to distinguish between moral statements and non-moral statemnts.
Consider the following statements:

1. You shouldn't steal things.
2. You shouldn't do imoral things.
3. You should be morally good.
4. You should follow your moral code.
5. You should behave morally.
6. Saving people's lives is morally good.

Is every sentence above considered a moral statement? Why?
I guess that the 1st and 6th sentences are moral statements. But I am not sure about the rest of the sentences.
Thanks.

Comment: Anything with "should" or "good" is value dependent, and when the implied values are moral (as opposed to pragmatic, etc.) so is the statement. The difference between 1,6 and 2-5 is that the former are ethical (apply directly to conduct) while the latter are [meta-ethical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-ethics) (apply to ethics itself).

Comment: One might say that 1 and 6 are synthetic and the others (with qualifications, esp. respecting 4) analytic. See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analytic-synthetic/